# Swift how to create and test an object with nil properties?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to get my head around optionals, let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Contact {

    var displayName:String

    init(displayName:String) {
        self.displayName = displayName
    }

}

class Contacts {
    func create(displayName:String) -> Contact {

        return Contact(displayName: displayName)
    }
}
```

as you can see the Contact class has a field displayName, but this value can be nil on initialization.

so to initialize this class I would normally do:

```
let contact = Contact(displayName: "Test Name")
```

but instead I want to be able to do this as well:

```
let contact = Contact()
```

or

```
let contact = Contacts().create()
```

Comment: I do not understand what problem you are having. Please detail the exact issue and the expected outcome.

Comment: let me modify my question to explain myself a bit better then

Comment: The `displayName` property is not optional (after your edit), so what do you expect that `let contact = Contact()` creates?

Comment: @RPK because this constructor will grow to hold many many parameters, which all will be optional

Comment: @MartinR yes, I edited it, because I wasn't sure it was the correct way, Contact() creates a contact with a nil displayName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the init parameter an optional `String?`, with a *default
value* `nil`:

```
class Contact {
    var displayName: String?

    init(displayName: String? = nil) {
        self.displayName = displayName
    }
}

let contact1 = Contact()
let contact2 = Contact(displayName: "John")
```

The same works for the `Contacts` class:

```
class Contacts {
    func create(displayName: String? = nil) -> Contact {
        return Contact(displayName: displayName)
    }
}

let contacts = Contacts()
let contact3 = contacts.create()
let contact4 = contacts.create("Mary")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class to this if you want to use an optional `displayName`:

```
class Contact {
    var displayName: String?

    convenience init(displayName: String) {
        self.init()
        self.displayName = displayName
    }
}
```

This allows you to to this:

```
let contact = Contact()
let otherContact = Contact(displayName: "Test Name")
```

EDIT:
Here's the create function as well:

```
class Contacts {
    func create() -> Contact {
        return Contact()
    }

    func create(displayName: String) -> Contact {
        return Contact(displayName: displayName)
    }
}
```

But I'd recommend this:

```
class Contact {
    var displayName: String?

    init(displayName: String?) {
        self.displayName = displayName
    }
}

class Contacts {
    func create(displayName: String?) -> Contact {
        return Contact(displayName: displayName)
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, that solves part of the problem, how about having a function with optional params and sending this optional to the Contact class?

    func create(displayName:String) -> Contact {

        return Contact(displayName: displayName)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Made the displayName property optional, like so:

`var displayName:String?`

Optionals can either hold nil or an actual value, in your case a string.